# Ansible vs Puppet - Agent "check-in"

Tags: ansible, puppet

When it comes to Ansible vs Puppet, what's the difference when the nodes are receiving their configuration?
I know that the Puppet agent checks in every 30 min to get their configuration.
How is this for Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Puppet agent runs every 30 minutes by default making sure the state of
>   the checked in node (server) is in the desired (described) state.
>   Ansible doesn’t have that mechanism so if you want a scheduler you
>   need to look at Ansible Tower which has recently become Open Source.
>   [Puppet vs Ansible](https://www.devopsgroup.com/2018/01/10/puppet-vs-ansible/)

Answer (score 0):

Ansible works on push model whereas puppet works on pull model i.e the nodes are pulling the configuration from the puppet master

Comment: The difference that I'm looking for is: 
Ansible is ad-hoc without AWK (Ansible Tower) since you have to ssh into the server and write `ansible playbook ...`  
While puppet checks automatically by default...

Comment: thats what is the push and pull method. puppet agent i.e the pull action checks for the configuration change. Ansible pushes via ssh ad-hoc or we can  use ansible-poll as well which in a way will act like pull but with limitations.

Comment: Have you any experience yourself, using Ansible AWX (Tower) to make this automatic?